# Ubuntu Core Proxy Settings at Boot Time

Tags: proxy, ubuntu-core

I installed 'Ubuntu Core 16' image on  Raspberry Pi3. During the first boot, I am required to configure network and enter my Ubuntu SSO credentials. The problem is I am behind my work firewall and am getting 'failed to connect to verify my Ubuntu SSO credentials. Apparently there is no way to configure proxy at the system boot time. Does someone know a workaround to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm too late for this question. But for anyone who's looking for an answer, the following worked for me.

Works for booting from SD card (first follow normal procedure to configure, then follow below steps)

1. Connect the SD card containing the Ubuntu core
2. Mount the 'linux filesystem' partition of SD card (verify using `sudo fdisk -l`)
3. Open the `environment` and add your proxy settings (Note: the mounted partition should contain `system-data/etc/`)

The steps are: (WARNING: SD card partition naming may change, verify before mounting)

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sdc9 /mnt
$ cd /mnt
$ sudo vim system-data/etc/environment
 # add the proxy settings
 https_proxy=https://<user>:<password>@<IP>:<port>
 http_proxy=http://<user>:<password>@<IP>:<port>
$ sudo umount /mnt
```

- Insert the card and boot
- Follow the configuration steps
- Now will be able to connect to proxy